# MySQL 60 days, 90 days and daily churn

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been working on churn analysis. I was successful in estimating the monthly churn based on the following code. This is the code which I have used

```
with monthly_usage as (
  select 
    who_identifier, 
    datediff(month, '1970-01-01', when_timestamp) as time_period
  from events
  where event = 'login' group by 1,2 order by 1,2),

lag_lead as (
  select who_identifier, time_period,
    lag(time_period,1) over (partition by who_identifier order by who_identifier, time_period),
    lead(time_period,1) over (partition by who_identifier order by who_identifier, time_period)
  from monthly_usage),

lag_lead_with_diffs as (
  select who_identifier, time_period, lag, lead, 
    time_period-lag lag_size, 
    lead-time_period lead_size 
  from lag_lead),

calculated as (select time_period,
  case when lag is null then 'NEW'
     when lag_size = 1 then 'ACTIVE'
     when lag_size > 1 then 'RETURN'
  end as this_month_value,

  case when (lead_size > 1 OR lead_size IS NULL) then 'CHURN'
     else NULL
  end as next_month_churn,

  count(distinct who_identifier)
   from lag_lead_with_diffs
  group by 1,2,3)

select time_period, this_month_value, sum(count) 
  from calculated group by 1,2
union
select time_period+1, 'CHURN', count 
  from calculated where next_month_churn is not null
order by 1
```

However, I would be interested in calculating 60 day, 90 day and daily churn. Is there any way I can tweak this code? I am new to SQL and currently working on MySQL. The code which I have shared has been translated to MySQL with same output as below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your datediff function to 'day' instead of month? Also, what is your table composed of?

This is how I'm getting to daily churn calculation:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks_used_da
            (
            date DATE,
            user_id BIGINT,
            account_id BIGINT,
            sum_tasks_used BIGINT
            )

WITH daily_churn as (
SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('day', date) as day, user_id
FROM tasks_used_da
WHERE sum_tasks_used > 0
)
SELECT yesterday.day, COUNT(DISTINCT yesterday.user_id)
FROM daily_churn yesterday
LEFT JOIN daily_churn today
  ON today.user_id = yesterday.user_id
  AND today.day = yesterday.day + interval '28 days'
WHERE today.user_id is null
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```